# How can you map counties to congressional districts?

Tags: geoprocessing

Given county A, I need to know what congressional districts are within it.

Comment: Do you have a platform that you prefer to work on?  You could do operations like this in proprietary desktop GIS applications, OpenSource desktop GIS applications, in a scripting language like Python, or as a query in a spatial database like PostGIS.

Comment: Based on your description, you are looking for a spatial operation like 'contains()'.  You may actually want an operation like 'intersects()' to identify all congressional districts that are fully or partially covered by a county.

Answer (score 1):

The Census has this data here:  http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cd110th/tables110.html

Comment: So it appears that it might be a case of counties in congressional districts, rather than the other way around?

Comment: The Congressional Districts and Counties file (http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cd110th/natl_code/cou_cd110_natl.txt), lists counties and CD, with one row for each combination.  Pair it with the County table here and you should be set: http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cd109th/fips_to_cou_name.txt